# 逃げられた (full sentence)

Tags: potential-form, passive-voice

A girl ties up a cat and puts it in the corner. She's not paying attention and it escapes. When she looks in the corner she sees the ropes, and she sees that the cat is gone, and she says "逃げられた".

Is that （猫が）逃げられた = 逃げることが出来た, or is it （私は猫に）逃げられた?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the first one is meant to be the potential form, and the second one is meant to be the passive form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter, passive.

cf. やられた！

Comment: I agree. But why? We still haven't seen a good explanation why the "It was able to escape" reading is unnatural. If the reading were to be potential, I would expect something like "よく逃げられたねぇ", but I can't really explain why.

Answer (score 1):

It is 猫に逃げられた, which expresses the fact that the speaker has suffered some damage from the event.  私は can be placed at the beginning but it is not essential.  Native speakers would omit it over 95% of the time.

猫が逃げられた makes no sense whatsoever.

However,　something like　猫がネズミに逃げられた。 makes sense.  The cat is the one that suffered damage from letting the mouse go in this sentence.

Comment: The second paragraph and the third paragraph are contradicting each other.

Comment: どう思ってもらおうが自由ですけれど…。

Comment: @TokyoNagoya そんなことないでしょ～今までのダウンボート、トータルでたったの２回よ。Reputation>>>view moreで見たけど。

Comment: @T.Ito If you are a native speaker, you know that 猫が逃げられた could not be said without the mention of what escaped from him prior to the sentence in the context.  That is what I meant by "That makes no sense."

Comment: In other words, both 猫が逃げられた and 猫がネズミに逃げられた make sense in appropriate contexts.  Neither makes sense in the context stated in the question.  Why do you state one “makes no sense whatsoever” and the other “makes sense”?

Comment: I cannot believe I am speaking to a Japanese speaker here. The sentence 猫がネズミに逃げられた makes perfect sense all by itself.  It contains all the information for a sentence to make sense without further context.  猫が逃げられた does not.

Comment: By the way, you do not have to believe that I am a Japanese speaker.  You belief means nothing to me.

Comment: @ちょこれーと　何だよ、たったの２回って？「目星が付いてる」っていうのイトーさんのことじゃないよ。イトーさんと私の最初のコメの投稿時間見てよ。私はちょこさんのコメに応答しただけだよ。イトーさんのコメ見てから「誰だかわかる」って言ったんじゃないよ。ってなんでこんなこと二カ国語で説明しなきゃなんないんだよ！

Comment: 「二回」って、このポストが二回ダウンされてるって意味じゃないですよ。Tokyoさんがこのサイトに参加されて以来、Tokyoさんの回答にダウンが入ったのは二回だから、「回答者が私だと自動的にDVするアホがいる」ってのはなさそうだって意味だったんですが・・・

Comment: I am afraid some (multiple?) misunderstanding is going on here.  I cannot post more comments on the site for a day, but I will try to catch up the conversation after that.

Comment: guys, the first sentence was supposed to be the potential form! so it would be something like "the cat was able to escape" or "the cat managed to escape". what happened to chocolate's answer? i liked that one.

Comment: @ogicu8abruok She deleted it.  (I liked it, too!)

Comment: えっ。。どうしよう・・・---

Comment: Tokyo's answer makes sense to me although "猫が逃げられた by itself does make sense without context. However...." might be a tighter explanation then "猫が逃げられた makes no sense whatsoever".  (People often use absolute statements from time to time to emphasize their point even though they are not absolutely[ ;-) ] correct.)